# Mysql query with multiple ands and ors

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a filter function for servers on my site. Users are able to check different options for the categories they want to filter for, and I have an ajax request that returns the servers satisfying their conditions. However, my mysql_query isn't working, I think I might have the wrong syntax.

By default, each category has the option set as 1. My current query is:

```
$order = "SELECT * FROM `servers` 
    WHERE `size` = '$size' or 
      1 = '$size' and 
      `type` = '$type' or 
      1 = '$type' and 
      `mode` = '$gamemode' or 
      1 = '$gamemode' and 
      `main` = '$main' or 
      1 = '$main' 
    ORDER BY $orderby 
    LIMIT 5";
```

It doesn't seem to get the correct servers, do I have an error in my query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When mixing `and` and `or` in your query you must use parenthesis to group the conditions.  Also, I think when you say 1 = '$size', I think you mean `` `size`=1 ``.

```
$order = "SELECT * FROM `servers` 
WHERE 
  (`size` = '$size' or `size` = '1') and 
  (`type` = '$type' or `type` = 1) and 
  (`mode` = '$gamemode' or `mode`= 1 ) and 
  (`main` = '$main' or `main` = 1) 
ORDER BY $orderby 
LIMIT 5";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"SELECT * FROM `servers` WHERE 
`size` in ('$size', 1) and 
`type` in( '$type' ,1) and 
`mode` in('$gamemode' ,1) and 
`main` in ( '$main' , 1 ) 
ORDER BY $orderby LIMIT 5";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add parentheses because `or` and `and` have a different order of operations and needs parentheses to allow what you are needing to accomplish

```
SELECT * FROM `servers` WHERE
(`size` = '$size' or 1 = '$size') and
(`type` = '$type' or 1 = '$type') and
(`mode` = '$gamemode' or 1 = '$gamemode') and
(`main` = '$main' or 1 = '$main')
ORDER BY $orderby LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

you must have to use brackets to use multiple OR condition in query

like

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM servers WHERE email='$Email' AND (date='$Date_Today' OR date='$Date_Yesterday' OR date='$Date_TwoDaysAgo' OR date='$Date_ThreeDaysAgo' OR date='$Date_FourDaysAgo')");
```

you can change with your column name

and also you can use IN condtion like

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM servers WHERE email='$Email' AND date IN ('$Date_Today','$Date_Yesterday','$Date_TwoDaysAgo')");
```

pls let me know if i can help you more

Answer (score 0):

Just try to put brace around the `or` conditions

```
$order = "SELECT * FROM `servers` WHERE (`size` = '$size' or 1 = '$size') and (`type` = '$type' or 1 = '$type') and (`mode` = '$gamemode' or 1 = '$gamemode') and (`main` = '$main' or 1 = '$main') ORDER BY '$orderby' LIMIT 5";
```